# Recording/showing score JS game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a leaderboard to this game so you can enter your name at the end and scores are recorded.

Failing that just displaying the users score at the end rather than it just reverting to the "start game" button automatically would suffice.

Id also like to add touch capability for mobiles/tablets.

Ive copied the code below along with a jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/goktxe84/

```
<button id="start">Start Game</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

```
  display:none;
}

button{
   height:20px; 
    width:100px; 
    margin: -20px -50px; 
    position:relative;
    top:50%; 
    left:50%;
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#canvas").addClass("displayNone");
    $("#start").click(function(){
        $("#start").addClass("displayNone");
      $("#canvas").removeClass("displayNone");
    })
    var keys = [];
        window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
        switch(e.keyCode){
            case 37: case 39: case 38:  case 40: 
            case 32: e.preventDefault(); break; 
            default: break; 
        }
    },
false);
window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e){
        keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    },
false);
    var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = $("#canvas").width();
    var h = $("#canvas").height();

    var cw = 10;
    var d;
    var food;
    var score;

    var snake_array;

    function init() {
        d = "right"; 
        create_snake();
        create_food(); 
        score = 0;

        if (typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
        game_loop = setInterval(paint, 90);
    }
    init();

    function create_snake() {
        var length = 5; 
        snake_array = []; 
        for (var i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            snake_array.push({
                x: i,
                y: 0
            });
        }
    }

    function create_food() {
        food = {
            x: Math.round(Math.random() * (w - cw) / cw),
            y: Math.round(Math.random() * (h - cw) / cw),
        };
    }

    function paint() {
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.strokeRect(0, 0, w, h);

        var nx = snake_array[0].x;
        var ny = snake_array[0].y;

        if (d == "right") nx++;
        else if (d == "left") nx--;
        else if (d == "up") ny--;
        else if (d == "down") ny++;

        if (nx == -1 || nx == w / cw || ny == -1 || ny == h / cw || check_collision(nx, ny, snake_array)) {
        $("#start").removeClass("displayNone");
      $("#canvas").addClass("displayNone");
            init();
            return;
        }

        if (nx == food.x && ny == food.y) {
            var tail = {
                x: nx,
                y: ny
            };
            score++;

            create_food();
        }
        else {
            var tail = snake_array.pop(); 
            tail.x = nx;
            tail.y = ny;
        }

        snake_array.unshift(tail); 
        for (var i = 0; i < snake_array.length; i++) {
            var c = snake_array[i];
            paint_cell(c.x, c.y);
        }

        paint_cell(food.x, food.y);
        var score_text = "Score: " + score;
        ctx.fillText(score_text, 5, h - 5);
    }

    function paint_cell(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "pink";
        ctx.fillRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
        ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
        ctx.strokeRect(x * cw, y * cw, cw, cw);
    }

    function check_collision(x, y, array) {
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i].x == x && array[i].y == y) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == "37" && d != "right") d = "left";
        else if (key == "38" && d != "down") d = "up";
        else if (key == "39" && d != "left") d = "right";
        else if (key == "40" && d != "up") d = "down";
    })

})
```

Comment: Hi @gjjr , what have you tried and what's not working? :)

Comment: Hi Will, I have only tried the suggested code below which doesnt seem to work. I need the score to be displayed once you lose. Also a much more long winded request but I need to make it work on mobile so the user touches the screen to move the "snake".

Comment: Will, the score is now being displayed once you lose, but it resets back to 0 after a few seconds, how can I make the score stay visible until you restart the game? https://jsfiddle.net/whrtngk9/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for show latest result add html element, where you can show it

```
<button id="start">Start Game</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<span id="score"></span>
```

and change text on this element, when you lose (line 79)

```
...
 if (nx == -1 || nx == w / cw || ny == -1 || ny == h / cw || check_collision(nx, ny, snake_array)) {
        document.querySelector('#score').innerText = 'Your latest score = ' + score; 
        $("#start").removeClass("displayNone");
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, it works, I just needed to change the bottom line to stop the game restarting automatically


      $("#start").removeClass("displayNone");
      $("#canvas").addClass("displayNone");

Comment: The score is displaying at the end, but it resets back to 0 after a few seconds??? You can see that behaviour here - https://jsfiddle.net/whrtngk9/4/

Comment: The score is also displaying on the start screen rather than just being triggered when you lose?

Comment: as solution: define score variable in outer scope, and then set it to zero only on click start button
https://jsfiddle.net/anob4guw/